# Error reading large virtual raster with rasterio: "Cannot invert degenerate transform"

Tags: python, raster, gdal, coordinate-system, rasterio

I've created a virtual raster using `gdalbuildvrt`, which covers a large extent (England) at a high resolution. The data is fairly sparse, focused around the coastlines with no files covering inland areas. I'm trying to read the data in Python using `rasterio`.

When I try to invert the affine transformation (to get world coordinates converted to pixel coordinates) I getting the following error:

```
>>> layer.affine
Affine(0.0002777778000000001, 0.0, -5.5000000044,
       0.0, -0.0002777778000000001, 55.0000000836)
>>> layer.affine.__invert__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\affine-1.0-py2.7.egg\affine\__init__.py", line 407, in __invert__
    "Cannot invert degenerate transform")
affine.TransformNotInvertibleError: Cannot invert degenerate transform
```

I don't get this error accessing the individual raster files. I have some idea of what it means, but not how to work around it. Perhaps it needs approaching in a different way? How do I access this data without having to worry about which file it's stored in?

Comment: I cannot find docs for `__invert__` but I suspect it is a general matrix inversion procedure.  The 2 by 3 matrix returned by `layer.affine` cannot be inverted *as a matrix* (because it is not square).  If I am correct, you would need to apply a procedure intended specifically for this shorthand representation of affine transformations, perhaps [invertAffineTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#invertaffinetransform).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverting the transform isn't the way to go. Try the dataset's `index()` method or its code: https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/rasterio/io.py#L62.